# ReactJS call function once if query strings set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, next.js

**Explain:**

In `useEffect` I get products via `getProducts()` function based on given `data` and data contains search filters and will be update by user so need to watch it in realtime, for example data contains an object like this `{brand: 'x'}`

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
  getProducts(data) // get products via api based on data, if data is clear, it will return all products
    .then(data => {
      //
    });
}, [data]) // watch data in realtime and send it to getProducts()

useEffect(() => {
  getQuery(); // check if there are search querys
}, [])
```

Also there is a `getQuery()` function, it will check if there are any query strings in search params when page is reload, and will get query strings and set it to `data`, and by above code if `data` get update it will call `getProducts()` again, actually it update products.

```
const getQuery = () => {
  let obj_url = new URL(window.location.href);
  let params = obj_url.searchParams;
  let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(params);

  // some other code 
  setData(obj); // get query and set it to data
}
```

**Problem:**

I noticed while there are query strings in url it will call `getProducts()` twice! well this code definitely does that, but I don't want it, how can I prevent to call this twice? I just want if there are query strings call once, if not call once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will call it once for the initialization of `useState`, and second time for the updated data from `getQuery` on the `useEffect`. You don't really need a `useEffect` for the `getQuery` function. You can just set the data from query on the initial state directly (the initial state will only be set on the initial render anyway, not on subsequent ones).

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(getQuery());

useEffect(() => {
  getProducts(data) // get products via api based on data, if data is clear, it will return all products
    .then(data => {
      //
    });
}, [data]) // watch data in realtime and send it to getProducts()

const getQuery = () => {
  let obj_url = new URL(window.location.href);
  let params = obj_url.searchParams;
  let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(params);

  // some other code
  return obj ?? {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bad idea to use that function in state `initialization`, you can do this with native way, `react-router-dom`. Based on `@Cristian-Florin Calina` answer, I provide new answer:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const Router = useRouter();
const [data, setData] = useState(Router.query);

useEffect(() => {
  getProducts(data)
    .then(data => {
      //
    });
}, [data]);
```

`Router.query` return all search params and with this there is no need to call `getQuery` function. *easy!*

Comment: why is it a bad idea? it’s not the greatest to use window location indeed, i provided a solution for his problem, not an improvement. Also, he might want to parse the query params in his function and not set everything from query params on the state.

Comment: if you read the docs (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) they even give examples of using a function in the initial state so I don’t understand what is bad about it.

Comment: @Cristian-FlorinCalina I didn't say your answer is wrong or bad idea, OP function is bad idea, but one of the point of a good answer is improve and choose best method, when OP can get search params in native way and less codes, why should involve with URL Object, also OP can filter each search params for own function.

Comment: Thanks @Pedram looks better but there is problem here, when I use your code, even I get params in log but its not update `setData` I don't know why. But I used Cristian answer it works fine only I got this error `expected server HTML to contain a matching <span> in <div>.` when I use it. any idea? @Cristian ?

Comment: @tourtravel Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67256421/is-there-any-way-to-suppress-hydration-warning-in-react-fc